# Angularjs ng-material not working in MVC5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working with MVC5 and angukarJS and i want to use angularJS material in mt project. I downloaded all the required packets but i am stuck at 1 point. Whenever i try to use ng-material my screen becomes blank.

`var app = angular.module("myApp", []);` it shows my form but CSS not showing.

`var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngmaterial']);`Screen become blank.

Comment: In mY bundle.config   
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include( 
                      "~/Content/angular-material.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.layout-attributes.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.layout-attributes.min.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.layouts.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.layouts.ie_fixes.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.layouts.min.css",
                      "~/Content/angular-material.min.css"));

Comment: Where do you load 'angular-material.min.js'. As far as I understand you want to inject this https://material.angularjs.org/latest/getting-started

Comment: module name is `"ngMaterial"` not `"ngmaterial"`. Please note all errors thrown when asking questions

Comment: i tried with ngMaterial before ngmaterial but i was missing 1 reference. All good now. Thanks for help and response.